# Building Tensorflow Lite for iOS with Conan

Tags: cmake, bazel, tensorflow-lite, conan

I am trying to build Tensorflow Lite with conan. I can see that there is a CMake file in Tensorflow Lite included but it seems like iOS is not supported. Is the only way to build it with conan to use bazel?

I am trying to use this CMakefile and it explicitly states that iOS is not supported: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a3e2c692c18649329c4210cf8df2487d2028e267/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L23

I found this conan file that uses bazel: https://github.com/DoumanAsh/conan-tensorflow-lite/blob/master/conanfile.py
But it seems like its is outdated. Is that the way to go?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. Like ``conan install --require=tensorflow-lite/version --build=tensorflow*`` or something like that? And how it is failing? Or just executing CMake of the tensorflow-lite repo (link please), but how is Conan involved in that? More detailed explanation would be useful.